# Does my ZF app cause "request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects" errors?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, http-redirect, redirect-loop

We've an eCommerce site developed with ZendFrameWork v1.10. Sometimes site is loads extremely slowly, and many pages are not loading at all and are timing out. The homepage is taking upwards of 15 seconds to load, and many product pages do not load at all and simply time out.

Often times for this case we restart our apache server and site up as normal . Then we inquired the server providers they said our server health is good and they produce our server health status as like this

```
(~) # uptime
 12:00:17 up 655 days, 10:51,  2 users,  load average: 0.87, 0.65, 0.58

(~) # uptime
 12:00:29 up 177 days,  6:46,  1 user,  load average: 0.64, 0.53, 0.47
```

Also they advised us to check our server error_log because they found many php errors are loading to it. When we checking the server erro_log and it's old files. We found many of the following error in all our log files.

```
[Sun Dec 30 02:35:32 2012] [error] [client 66.249.76.16] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

If I checked the above error for certain IP in the error_log file `eg : 66.249.76.16` I found 6 results and if I checked the IP stripping off the last two digits from it `(66.249.76)` I can see more than 20 errors per day like above in our error_log file.

I think, the first problem I should solve is the above "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace" Apache log problem.

We have gone through logs and it happens daily as mentioned above, so I need to find out what code is actually causing this bug. We asked our server support to enable "Loglevel debug" (I'm not too familiar with this) but I still cannot see anything useful or any difference in our error log after enabling this.

My question is - what can I do to find out where in our site this error is being generated? It would be very helpful to know which PHP script (we have 100s) is actually making this "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects" redirect happen.

Any recommendations of how I can proceed?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the ZF application is the cause here?  What else is hosted on the server?

Comment: No actually we're not sure this issue is causing from ZF application. Yes we've installed Word Press in our server but it's pretty much it's own configuration. We've not changed anything from that setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also had some issues like this. We made a log in the index.php, which gave us a pretty good idea which request is causing the issue. You can implement the same and check from which requests are taking most execution time.

```
<?php

define('EXECUTION_START',  microtime(true));

.
.
.
// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH .DS. 'configs'.DS.'application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();

$endTime = microtime(true);
$executionTime = $endTime-EXECUTION_START;
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$logString="$ipaddress|$url|$startTime|$endTime|$executionTime\n";
$file = 'executiontime.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $logString, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: We tried this and figured out that the redirection errors are most likely because of .htaccess doing some of its own redirects, as the error log entries' timings never match our custom log entries. For example for one IP, if a redirect happens at 07:00 (in the Apache error log) - there isn't a match for this in our custom error log. perhaps a match a half hour later or but never exact match. This tells me our Zend application isn't even being accessed during these logs If you know a way to possible log what .htaccess is doing (i.e. which URLs are causing redirect problems, please let me know.

Comment: The time difference can be because of the server and application timeszones are different. If you are using c-Panel there is a `Logs->Raw Access Log` option. May be that logs will help you to identify the error.

Comment: Thanks man we finally found the answer. It seems to be bots and 404 pages are causing this issue.  I don't know why I might need to post a another forum post to explain that issue. Thanks again to your help and time.